# R lmer with variance structure

Tags: r, lme4, nlme

i want to fit a mixed model but with variance structure.

I create my data frame

```
DTF <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(7*4, 0, 1),
                  TIME = rep(1:7, 4),
                  GROUP = c(rep(1,7), rep(2,7), rep(3,7), rep(4,7)),
                  X = rep(rnorm(7, 20, 5), 4))
```

and than i run this command

```
model <- lmer(Y ~ TIME:GROUP + X + (1 | GROUP), DTF, REML = FALSE,
              varWeights(varFixed(~ TIME)))
```

and i have

```
Error in lmer(...): 'control' is not a list; use lmerControl()
```

I don't know what i have to change.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you can't use nlme variance structures within lme4 models. You'll have to switch to nlme entirely. (Also, the fourth parameter of `lmer` is `control` and not `weights`.)

Comment: I think that i can do it. But thanks, the problem was in the order or parameters. <blink> model <- lmer(Y ~ TIME:GROUP + X + (1|GROUP), data=DTF, REML=FALSE, control = lmerControl(),  varWeights(varFixed(~ TIME))) </blink>

Comment: I can only reiterate: I don't believe this fits a variance structure. Compare models with and without `weights` specified like this. They will have exactly the same fit.

Comment: touche! you're right. but also with nlmer i have the same thing.

Comment: `nlme::lme` is the function you should use! NOT `lme4::nlmer`!